# How do i get the summary descriptive statistics for a quantitative variable over a qualitative variable?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that gives me the fuel economy on the highway, among other variables for 4 and 6 cylinder cars. I tried using the group_by function which is not working ( code to follow)

I have installed and deployed / called the dplyr package but it throws an error

> Error in group_by(., Cylinders) : could not find function "group_by"

```
Cars_filtered %>% group_by(Cylinders) %>% summarise(Min = min(Economy_highway,na.rm = TRUE),
                                                    Q1 = quantile(Economy_highway,probs = .25,na.rm = TRUE),
                                                    Median = median(Economy_highway, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                    Q3 = quantile(Economy_highway,probs = .75,na.rm = TRUE),
                                                    Max = max(Economy_highway,na.rm = TRUE),
                                                    Mean = mean(Economy_highway, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                    SD = sd(Economy_highway, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                    n = n(),
                                                    Missing = sum(is.na(price))
```

I want to see the summary descriptive stats for highway fuel economy for the different 4 and 6 cylinder cars .

Is there some other way to go about it?

Comment: Start the script with `library(dplyr)`. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(Cars_filtered)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(Cars_filtered, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

for this it would be sufficient to use  `tapply`.

Using the `mtcars` data set, let's say you are interested in the summary stats of MPG grouped by `gear`, you can use:

`tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$gear, summary)`

If you only want to retrieve the summary stats for gear "3" and "4", you can use add

`tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$gear, summary)[c("3", "4")]`

In case you want to add e.g. the standard deviation or sample size to the default summary output, you could define your own summary function:

```
smmry <- function(x) c(summary(x), sd = sd(x), n = length(x))

tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$gear, smmry)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan ! it doesn't report standard deviation though

Comment: And for a single matrix, rbind all elements: `do.call(rbind, tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$gear, smmry))`.